# Getting the output of %%time to log time of jupyter cells

Tags: python, time, jupyter

I want to log the times that Jupyter cells take to it but I want this in a single variable without multiple line if possible. It also cannot be a decorator as not every cell is a function.

Imagine the below is a single cell.

```
%%time
[x for x in range(1,1000000)]
```

CPU times: total: 125 ms
Wall time: 174 ms

Assigning `%%time` to a variable is not on option as I have tried but is there another way of doing this so I can then log the time.

I know this solution works but I was hoping for an elegant one liner:

```
start = time.time()

[x for x in range(1,1000000)]

time.time() - start
```